# Mysql ADDTIME function giving error Truncated incorrect time value: '35 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql, datetime

Trying to understand how does `ADDTIME()` actually works.
Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  update_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample data:

```
+-----+-----------------------+
| id  |      update_time      |
+-----+-----------------------+
| 1   | 2017-09-13 18:55:24   |
| 2   | 2017-08-10 18:53:16   |
+-----+-----------------------+
```

If i executes the following query, it gives me error:

```
UPDATE table3 SET update_time = ADDTIME(NOW(), '60 00:00:00') WHERE id=1;  

Error Code: 1292  
Truncated incorrect time value: '60 00:00:00'
```

Although following query works fine:

```
UPDATE table3 SET update_time = ADDTIME(NOW(), '5 00:00:00') WHERE id=1;
```

Tried to keep increasing the value of `DAY` and found it works fine till `DAY=34` and breaks for `DAY > 34`;
Could not found a clear answer why it breaks after a limit. Can some please explain how it is working?
PS: I know that `DATE_ADD()` can be used instead, I am using MySql 5.7.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual:

> MySQL recognizes TIME values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in 'D HH:MM:SS' format. You can also use one of the following “relaxed” syntaxes: 'HH:MM:SS', 'HH:MM', 'D HH:MM', 'D HH',
>     or 'SS'. **Here D represents days and can have a value from 0 to 34.**
> - As a string with no delimiters in 'HHMMSS' format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, '101112' is understood as
>     '10:11:12', but '109712' is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part)
>     and becomes '00:00:00'.
> - As a number in HHMMSS format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, 101112 is understood as '10:11:12'. The following
>     alternative formats are also understood: SS, MMSS, or HHMMSS.

The restriction is related to the range of the time type (and most likely the underlying storage requirements) as indicated in [the answer by @ReneS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615956/1175077)

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Answer (score 2):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html:

> TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'

```
838:59:59 = 34 days 22 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use `DATE_ADD()` instead of `ADDTIME()`, as the former would convert your `TIMESTAMP`/`DATETIME` values to `DATE` and loose the time parts...

Use [`TIMESTAMPADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) instead:

```
UPDATE table3 SET update_time = TIMESTAMPADD( DAY, 60, NOW() ) WHERE id = 1;
```